# Iphone internet radio

Tags: objective-c, audio-streaming, shoutcast, internet-radio

I am trying to make my own internet radio app for Iphone and Ipad. I read documentation and I found Matt Gallagher example code but it doesn't work with my radio (a shoutcast server streaming mp3 audio).

Is it possible that in 2011 we have to deal with C structure, call back function, run loop, void pointer in a very very low level programming style?

Is there an high level framework to deal with audio streams just like in others platform/language?

Thanks